# Converting Excel formula to SharePoint Calculated column formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, excel, calculated-column-formula

I'm pretty new to SharePoint calculated formulas and am struggling to convert an Excel formula I have to a SharePoint calculated column formula.

The Excel formula is
=FLOOR(280-(J5-TODAY()),7)/7&" weeks "&MOD(280-(J5-TODAY()),7)&" days"

In my SharePoint calculated formula, 'J5' would be replaced by '[EDD]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
Tom

Comment: what is the column type of [EDD]?

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Create a **Date and time** column named **[EDD]**

[image]

2.Create a **Calculated** column named **[TEST123]**

3.Use the below Formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(ROUNDDOWN((280-([EDD]-TODAY())+1)/7,0)," Weeks , ",MOD(280-([EDD]-TODAY()),7)," Days ")
```

[image]

[image]